# Is there a way in Eclipse CDT to make the IDE parser to read ifndef sections?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have a section like the following:

```
#ifndef __CUSTOM_TYPE
typedef unsigned int u_int;
#endif
```

The IDE doesn't parse it although there is no __CUSTOM_TYPE defined.
Then it reports the usage of u_int as an error.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle that should work. Assuming the file is correctly configured to be a C file in a C project (i.e. has a .c icon), CDT shows by colour coding which lines it is counting as part of the selected build configuration. So if __CUSTOM_TYPE is not defined, the following line should have a different background colour.

If that is not the case, hovering over the __CUSTOM_TYPE symbol should bring up an indication of where it is defined - perhaps in some nested header file or something.